# Is it possible to shift just one bit within the bit shift?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

My question is whether I can only switch bits **B6, B5** to create a toUpper() function or if I would need to split the bits into separate parts

[image: ASCII Bit representations]
An example shift of this type would be:

1000001 to 1100001
(**A** to **a**)

Comment: you can xor (the `^` operator) your char with `0x20` to switch between cases.

Comment: "shift" has a different meaning in this context.  What you mean is set/reset bits.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift just one bit using masking but there is a much simpler way.

```
if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z')
    ch -= 'a' - 'A'; // subtract 32
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final int BIT5 = 0x20;

int A = 0b1000001;
int a = setBits(A, BIT5);

public static int setBits(int val, int bits) {
    return val | bits;
}

public static int clearBits(int val, int bits) {
    return val & ~bits;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, So you are just grabbing each individual bit.. thanks.